# Hiding points in shapefile layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, editing, expression

I am using QGIS 3.4

I would like to hide all points that end with "5". For example, I would like to hide: 55, 65, 75, 85 and any point ending in "5".

What method can be use to make this possible?

[image: Shapefile]

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way, using the same method as presented above by Joseph, with a slightly shorter code:

```
if(LABEL % 10 = 5,"","LABEL")
```

When the remainder of dividing by 10 is 5 (so 5, 15, 25...) it won't show the point. 
[image]

Comment: Seems to be partly working. But the map is still displaying "5" intervals. See [picture here](http://i.imgur.com/lNUVEIX.png) @Joseph

Comment: it's because you have to get rid of the additional "universal" symbol at the bottom - https://imgur.com/a/MrDLGBD

Comment: And add the same code I provided in the "Labels" menu if you don't want the labels to be displayed https://imgur.com/a/22cbVMr

Comment: Ahh Thank you very much regarding the "Universal" symbol. Working perfectly now!  @Pawel

Answer (score 4):

We can use the modulus operator `%` to calculate the remainder values when dividing by 5. If there is no remainder then it is removed from the display. However, because multiples of 10 can be divided by 5 with no remainder, we will have to exclude this by adding some logic to the expression:

```
if("LABEL" % 5 = 0 AND NOT "LABEL" % 10 = 0, "LABEL" % 5 AND NOT "LABEL" % 10, "LABEL")
```

---

[image: Excluding values ending in 5]

Comment: Seems to be partly working. But the map is still displaying "5" intervals. See picture here https://i.imgur.com/lNUVEIX.png @Pawel

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the layer, click on "Filter..." and enter the expression `LABEL % 10 != 5` into the text field labelled "Provider specific filter expression", then press OK.